# How to find the index of an item in an array of class in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

Well first of all we all know that finding an index of an array is easy but I got stump finding an index of an item in an array which contains multiple structs.

**This is my class:**

```
class Patient{
private var id: Int
private var name: String
private var gender: String
private var mileage: Double

//global variable
var globalPatientID:Int{
    return id
}
var globalPatientName:String{
    return name
}
var globalPatientGender:String{
    return gender
}
var globalPatientMileAge:Double{
    return mileage
}

init(id:Int, name:String, gender:String, mileage:Double){
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.mileage = mileage
    }
}
```

**This is my array:**

```
let AppUserID = prefs.objectForKey("AppUserID")

        for var i=0; i<nou; ++i{
            numberOfUsersExisting = nou

            if (AppUserID as? String == json[0][i]["App_ID"].stringValue){
                print("Assigning AppUserID")
                appUserMileage = json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue
            }

            pSample += [Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, gender: json[0][i]["Gender"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)]

            pSample.sortInPlace({$0.globalPatientMileAge < $1.globalPatientMileAge})
        }
```

So pSample is initially a blank array and it appends a class of items through a loop.

The sortInPlace function helps me to sort pSample based on globalPatientMilaAge.

So this got me thinking, how do I get the index of my AppUserID(which I cast it as a String) from the array of class?

I tried using this function but it doesn't seems working because I'm looping through classes instead of items inside a class.

```
appUserRanking = pSample.indexOf("\(AppUserID)")
```

Comment: What's the purpose of both private and public properties? If you want to have read-only properties just declare the properties as constants.

Comment: For future reference, the problem now is how to get the index from array of structs...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The body of `indexOf` can be a closure like the `map` and `filter` functions

```
appUserRanking = pSample.indexOf{$0.globalPatientID == AppUserID}
```

---

PS: It's pretty inefficient to get one object from json (`json[0][i]`) 6 times in the repeat loop.
Assign the object to a variable

```
let object = json[0][i]
```

and use it for example

```
if (AppUserID as? String == object["App_ID"].stringValue){
```

Comment: Yes it is indeed very insufficient to loop through just to get one object, so I actually use the function after the loop and it does a great job.

Answer (score 1):

Do like this,

```
let pSampleFiltered = pSample.filter {$0.globalPatientID == AppUserID}
if pSampleFiltered.count > 0 {
   if let index = pSample.indexOf(pSampleFiltered.first!) {
      // Do your stuff here
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not very efficient to filter the entire list.  indexOf with a closure argument is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3 and above mapping works like this

```
appUserRanking  = pSample.index(where: {$0.globalPatientID == AppUserID})
```